# @font-face VS @import

Tags: css, import, font-face

While defining a Web Font in CSS - I have noticed a small change in the way my font displays depending on which method of font definition I use:

```css
@font-face {url('https:/https://fonts.googleapis.com/...');}
```

[image: @font-face]

or

```css
@import url('https:/https://fonts.googleapis.com/...')
```

[image: @import]

with the `@import` I've got a lighter version of the font and with the `@font-face` method it is a bit bolder.

Can anyone tell me why this happens, what the differences between the 2 "methods" are, and which is more advisable (advantages vs disadvantages).

Answer (score 0):

Usually, `@font-face` is used to declare fonts that were downloaded and `@import` is for adding another stylesheet file. I would say that it could be related to font-weights. Because `@font-face` is creating the font that is downloaded it may be the problem. Does the google fonts link contain the font-weights?